# Importing table from csv file

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, csv

I have the following table in a avg_value.csv file:

```
,M23,F23_1,M36,F44,F63,M70
M23,1.00,0.81,0.88,0.83,0.41,0.82
F23_1,,1.00,0.52,0.56,0.25,0.94
M36,,,1.00,0.62,0.94,0.96
F44,,,,1.00,0.43,0.23
F63,,,,,1.00,0.22
M70,,,,,,1.00
```

and I want to import it in my LaTeX file.
Currently, I am using this code from http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html :

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
.
.
.
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule},
]
{pgfplotstable.avg_value.csv}
```

In fact, I do not import anything.

I receive as output message from kile:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file
>   'pgfplotstable.avg_value.csv'.

---

Changing the code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{pgfplotstable.avg_value.csv}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}}
]
{\mytable}
\caption[title.]{title.}
\label{tab:foo} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

did not solve the problem. Nothing really appears.

Comment: Try renaming the file to "test.csv" Is it working then? If so, try to avoid the dot after "stable"

Comment: Changing the file into test.csv and the last line into {pgfplotstable.test.csv} does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to describe the structure of the csv file to `pgfplotstable`. And you have subscripts in your column/row names that you need to take care of. I've just removed them.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% You don't need this part
% I did it to create your file 
\usepackage{filecontents} % <-- To create files on the fly

\begin{filecontents*}{avg_value.csv}
,M23,F231,M36,F44,F63,M70
M23,1.00,0.81,0.88,0.83,0.41,0.82
F231,,1.00,0.52,0.56,0.25,0.94
M36,,,1.00,0.62,0.94,0.96
F44,,,,1.00,0.43,0.23
F63,,,,,1.00,0.22
M70,,,,,,1.00
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
string replace*={_}{\textsubscript},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}}
]
{avg_value.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please have a look at the manual for a quickstart if you need to get a feeling for common options.

Comment: This way does not import any .csv file.

Comment: @werty Read my second paragraph

Comment: Do you mean writing \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{avg_value.csv}\mytable ?

Comment: @werty Yes exactly. Notice that underscore is a math active character in TeX in some cases it might cause problems so if you can, avoid it in file names and variables.

Comment: i did it, but nothing appears. Look at the addendum at the end of my question.

Comment: @werty See the edit wuth the explicit file

Comment: Everything works fine if I replace the underscore. So, the problem is almost solved. However, I need to specify the second column as "F23_1", so I have to maintain the underscore. In this case, the code does not work. Moreover, I was wondering if it is possible to draw a vertical line after the first column (i.e., the column with identifiers)

Comment: @werty Is it a text subscript or not? In math mode, it is easy.

Comment: In the .csv file is F23_1. It is an underscore, not a subscript.

Comment: @werty TeX thinks all underscores are subscripts and gives an error if you are not in math mode. That's why I'm trying to explain it

Comment: I see. I tried with F23\\_1 in the .csv, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @percusse I am sorry for asking this basic question, but could you tell me how to read a certain entry in `.csv` knowing its row and column numbers using `pgfplotstable` the same way done by `go to` in excel?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou `\pgfplotstablegetelem` can be used