# Dynamically color table elements while using an input file

Tags: tables, macros, color, pgfplotstable, external-files

I like to create a table from file ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262739/736)) and also dynamically color individual elements ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50351/736)). I'm not tied to pgfsplottable and not even share some combination with macros can produced the desired effect.

In the MWE below ([thanks!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262739/736)), I like to have the functionality of having any cell greater than 0.8 colored green. I don't want to hardcode the table because the input file may change.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
% I did it to create your file 
\usepackage{filecontents} % <-- To create files on the fly

\begin{filecontents*}{avg_value.csv}
,M23,F231,M36,F44,F63,M70
M23,1.00,0.81,0.88,0.83,0.41,0.82
F231,,1.00,0.52,0.56,0.25,0.94
M36,,,1.00,0.62,0.94,0.96
F44,,,,1.00,0.43,0.23
F63,,,,,1.00,0.22
M70,,,,,,1.00
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
string replace*={_}{\textsubscript},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}}
]
{avg_value.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Table]

Answer (score 3):

This is a good chance to practice [pgfplotstable](/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable)'s `assign cell content`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
% I did it to create your file 
\usepackage{filecontents} % <-- To create files on the fly

\begin{filecontents*}{avg_value.csv}
,M23,F231,M36,F44,F63,M70
M23,1.00,0.81,0.88,0.83,0.41,0.82
F231,,1.00,0.52,0.56,0.25,0.94
M36,,,1.00,0.62,0.94,0.96
F44,,,,1.00,0.43,0.23
F63,,,,,1.00,0.22
M70,,,,,,1.00
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = comma,
    string replace*={_}{\textsubscript},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    display columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
    assign cell content/.code={
        \edef\tempcellcontent{#1}
        \ifx\tempcellcontent\empty
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tempcellcontent}
            %\message{^^J^^J#1}
        \else
            \ifdim#1pt>0.8pt
                \pgfmathparse{#1*400-300}
                \edef\tempcellcontent{\noexpand\cellcolor{green!\pgfmathresult!}#1}
                \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tempcellcontent}
            \else
                \edef\tempcellcontent{#1}
                \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tempcellcontent}
            %   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1}
            \fi
        \fi
    },
]
{avg_value.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]